# Deploying judge0 on AWS EC2

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2

I am trying to deploy judge0 CE on my AWS EC2 instance using docker. Unfortunately I am very new to docker so am blindly following installation instructions.

Since the default instance on AWS has an 8 GiB EBS I am running out of disk space. So I added another 20 GiB EBS volume and mounted it correctly. But when I run the `docker-compose up -d` command it attempts to install in the /var on the first EBS volume and of course runs out of disk space.

How do I get everything to be installed on the new EBS volume? If I really go through lots of documentation I may find an answer but my goal is only to get judge0 running for a project and may not understand the intricacies of docker so easily.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add more diskspace to the EC2 Instance.
**Edit Instance configuration > change the disk space to atleast 30 GB**